# why do i keep getting this error " Error report - ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis 00906. 00000 - "

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table project_supervisor (
   supervisor_ID VARCHAR2 (5) Primary key,
   last_name varchar2 (250),
   other_names varchar2 (250)
);

 CREATE TABLE Project_description 
 (
    project_id VARCHAR2 NOT NULL,
    project_title varchar,
    project_summary varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (project_id),
      FOREIGN KEY (supervisor_ID)
    REFERENCES  "project_supervisor" (supervisor_ID)
);
```

Comment: varchar and varchar2 columns in project_description need a length. The parser is expecting e.g. (5) but gets NOT NULL instead, leading it to say 'missing left parens' ('(')

Answer (score 0):

```
create table project_supervisor (
   supervisor_ID VARCHAR2 (5) Primary key,
   last_name varchar2 (250),
   other_names varchar2 (250)
);

 CREATE TABLE Project_description 
 (
    project_id VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    project_title varchar(100),
    project_summary varchar(100),
    supervisor_ID varchar(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (project_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (supervisor_ID) REFERENCES  project_supervisor (supervisor_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create them like this :

```
CREATE TABLE project_supervisor ( 
             supervisor_ID VARCHAR2 (5) Primary key, 
             last_name varchar2 (250), 
             other_names varchar2 (250) 
            );

CREATE TABLE Project_description ( 
             project_id VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
             supervisor_ID varchar(5), 
             project_title varchar(25), 
             project_summary varchar(25),
             CONSTRAINT pk_project_id PRIMARY KEY(project_id), 
             CONSTRAINT fk_supervisor_ID FOREIGN KEY(supervisor_ID) 
                        REFERENCES project_supervisor (supervisor_ID) 
            );
```

- You need to include length for a `varchar` column.
- `constraint` definitions must be properly formatted.
- `supervisor_ID` column is missing in the second statement.
- `project_supervisor` shouldn't be quoted.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/731a81)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `supervisor_ID` in the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE project_supervisor 
  ( 
     supervisor_id VARCHAR2 (5) PRIMARY KEY, 
     last_name     VARCHAR2 (250), 
     other_names   VARCHAR2 (250) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE project_description 
  ( 
     project_id      VARCHAR2 NOT NULL, 
     project_title   VARCHAR, 
     project_summary VARCHAR, 
     supervisor_id   VARCHAR2(5), 
     PRIMARY KEY (project_id), 
     FOREIGN KEY (supervisor_id) REFERENCES project_supervisor (supervisor_id) 
  );
```

Also, don't need `"` around the table name.